# Prove that any projection on a normed linear on a subspace satisfies $\|I-P\|\geq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a subspace of a normed linear space $N$.

Let $P$ be a (continous) projection  on $M$. 
Then

$$\|I-P\|\geq 1 $$

Comment: Since $(I-P)^2 = (I-P)$, you have $\|(I-P)\| = \|(I-P)^2\| \leq \|(I-P)\|\|(I-P)\|$.

Comment: oh..thank you...it is easy know..??@PrahladVaidyanathan

Comment: $I$ is a projection, and $\|I-I\|=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $||I-P||<1 \implies  P$ is invertible $\implies P=I$

Comment: $0$ is not invertible, unless it's a $0$-dimensional space.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks for poining out my mistake ..I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much.

Pick any projection on a normed linear space onto a subspace and then prove that it satisfies this inequality?

I don't think that's what you meant, but it bears that interpretation in normal English usage.  Just saying "every" instead of "any" costs nothing, except two keystrokes.

I take "projection" to mean an idempotent linear transformation, i.e. a linear transformation $P$ satisfying the equation $P^2=P$.  Let $Q=I-P$.  Then $Q^2 = (I-P)^2 = I - 2P + P^2 = I - 2P + P = I - P = Q$. Thus $Q=I-P$ is also a projection.  If $u = Qx$ then $\|Qu\| = \|Q(Qx)\| = \|Q^2 x\| = \|Qx\| = \|u\|$, so $\dfrac{\|Qu\|}{\|u\|} = 1$, and therefore
$$
\sup\left\{ \frac{\|Qv\|}{\|v\|} : v \in \text{domain} \right\} \ge 1.
$$

Comment: I am sorry. I couldnt understand ...whether this is giving $\|I-P\|\geq 1$?

Comment: @gloom : Sorry --- I didn't finish this.  How about now? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: waiting for the completion of the answer..@michael

Comment: @gloom : When I said "How about now?" I meant that at that point I had completed it. ${}\qquad{}$